# paralell foreach and progressbar

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I have a simple foreach loop that I would like to paralellize, here's my code (not paralellized for now):

```
foreach (string filename in ofdmulti.FileNames)
                    {
                        img.Add(new DicomImage(filename)); // fill images
                        Progress_Bar_Loading_Images.PerformStep();
                    }
```

Now, my big problem is the progressbar.. I get an error because it seems I can't update the progressbar on another thread than the one that got created..

any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: you could do with adding what UI system you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What do you mean by what UI system I'm using?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, UWP, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Background Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).  It has built in support for doing cross-thread UI calls so you don't have to do anything special for it.  Plus, it has events built in for updating progress bars.  [This tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) walked me through it when I first needed to do exactly that.

Comment: Wow I just realized how old this question is.  I hope someone can still find this useful.